# Android Spinner with adapter get force close?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have registration form and it has two edittexts and one spinner with adapter for gender selection and value from array, when I click register button and select a gender it's going successfully, but when I don't select a gender and click register button it  get force close ?

here is my complete code ....

MainActivity

```
EditText Fullname, Email;
Spinner GenderSpinner;
Button btnReg;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    Fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.full_name);
    Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);

    // Gender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Gender);

    GenderSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Gender);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> GenderAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.sex,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    GenderAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    GenderSpinner.setPrompt("SELECT YOUR GENDER");

    GenderSpinner.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
            GenderAdapter, R.layout.gender_nothing_selected, MainActivity.this));

    btnReg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReg);
    btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Read EditText dat
            String fullname = Fullname.getText().toString();
            String email = Email.getText().toString();
            String gender = GenderSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }
    });
}
```

}

NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter

```
protected static final int EXTRA = 1;
protected SpinnerAdapter adapter;
protected Context context;
protected int nothingSelectedLayout;
protected int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
protected LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
        int nothingSelectedLayout, Context context) {
    this(spinnerAdapter, nothingSelectedLayout, -1, context);
}

public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
        int nothingSelectedLayout, int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout,
        Context context) {
    this.adapter = spinnerAdapter;
    this.context = context;
    this.nothingSelectedLayout = nothingSelectedLayout;
    this.nothingSelectedDropdownLayout = nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return getNothingSelectedView(parent);
    }
    return adapter.getView(position - EXTRA, null, parent);

}

protected View getNothingSelectedView(ViewGroup parent) {
    return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedLayout, parent, false);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // BUG! Vote to fix!!
    // http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17128 - Spinner
    // does not support multiple view types
    if (position == 0) {
        return nothingSelectedDropdownLayout == -1 ? new View(context)
                : getNothingSelectedDropdownView(parent);
    }

    return adapter.getDropDownView(position - EXTRA, null, parent); // could
                                                                        }

protected View getNothingSelectedDropdownView(ViewGroup parent) {
    return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, parent,
            false);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    int count = adapter.getCount();
    return count == 0 ? 0 : count + EXTRA;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position == 0 ? null : adapter.getItem(position - EXTRA);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position == 0 ? getViewTypeCount() - EXTRA : adapter
            .getItemViewType(position - EXTRA);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return adapter.getViewTypeCount() + EXTRA;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return adapter.getItemId(position - EXTRA);
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return adapter.hasStableIds();
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return adapter.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return position == 0 ? false : true; // don't allow the 'nothing

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting `null` here

```
String gender = GenderSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

because nothing has been selected so `GenderSpinner.geSelecetedItem()` is `null` when you try to call `toString()` on it. You could set a selected item as the default item or if you want to force the user to choose an item then you can just check for `null` here when running this code and if it is then display a message to the user to choose a gender.

If you go with the second option then you may consider using `RadioButtons` as it will be more natural for the user or use a text hint as the default value of the `Spinner` with a message of something like "Please choose a gender"